# Background Image not Showing in React using Map function

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a slide component that I want to use to create a carousel in React. I want to use the images in the public/images folder as background images for the carousel. I created an array of objects where the image is stored in the "backgroundImage" property as shown in the code:

```js
    const featured = [
      {
        designation: 'Author',
        date: dateFormat,
        authorImage: '/images/person_1.jpg',
        backgroundImage: 'images/img_1.jpg',
        title: 'This is the first featured-post',
        category: 'Programming and Framework',
        commentCount: 5,
    },
{
        designation: 'member board of editors',
        date: dateFormat,
        authorImage: '/images/person_1.jpg',
        backgroundImage: 'images/img_2.jpg',
        title: 'This is the second featured-post',
        category: 'Industry Insight',
        commentCount: 12,
    },
    {
    designation: 'Member',
        date: dateFormat,
        authorImage: '/images/person_1.jpg',
        backgroundImage: 'images/img_3.jpg',
        title: 'This is the third featured-post',
        category: 'IoT',
        commentCount: 1512,
     }
]
```

In the slide component, I created a map function to extract the image from the array and save it in a variable "featImg" as shown in the code below:

```js
import React from 'react';
import featured from '../pages/featured_news';

const Slides = () => {
  const featImg = featured.map((feat) => (feat.backgroundImage)
  );

  return (
    <div
      className="flex"
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${featImg})`,
        height: '300px',
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundColor: 'green',
        backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
      }}
    ></div>
  );
};

export default Slides;
```

When I start the server (npm start), the background images are not showing in the browser.
Using the inspection tool, the image is showing as strings like so,
background-image: url("images/img_1.jpg,images/img_2.jpg,images/img_3.jpg");
Instead of showing the actual background images.

Please what did I do wrong in the code, I need some corrections please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small misunderstanding of how `map` works. At the moment you're mapping over the array of objects and returning a *new* array of background image names. You're then applying that array to *one* element that you're returning from the component.

What you should be doing is including the creation of that element *within* the `map` process so that on each iteration a new element is created with the background image name *of that current iterated object*.

And then you return the whole array of newly-created elements from the component.

```
import React from 'react';
import featured from '../pages/featured_news';

const Slides = () => {
  return featured.map(feat => {
    return (
      <div
        className="flex"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${feat.backgroundImage)})`,
          height: '300px',
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
        }}
      />
    );  
  });
};

export default Slides;
```

Note: depending on how you call the this component you may want to wrap this returned code in a parent element:

```
const Slides = () => {
  return (
    <div class="slideWrapper">
      {featured.map(feat => {
        ...
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are passing `featImg` as `background-image`. `featImg` is an array of image url(s). You need to pass an element of the array like: `featImg[0]`. And if you are trying to put multiple backgrounds in a single div, you can not do that.

If you want to create multiple div(s) with background images from array `featImg`, You could use something like:

```
import React from 'react';
import featured from '../pages/featured_news';

const Slides = () => {
  const featImg = featured.map((feat) => (feat.backgroundImage));

  return (
    <>
      {featImg.map( element => {
          return (
            <div key={`divImg_${element}`} className="flex"
              style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${element})`,
              height: "300px",
              backgroundSize: "cover",
              backgroundColor: "green",
              backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat"
              }} >
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};

export default Slides;
```